# What is the better way to do service discovery on Docker environment?

Tags: docker, dns, haproxy, docker-swarm

I would like to listen your experience about service discovery on Docker environment.

We plan to have multi-host docker environment with Swarn.
The latest version of Docker provides internal DNS and round-robin feature.
Our idea is to use Docker overlay network.

I believe that one overlay network per application is the way to go, so every environment will be segmented in a specific subnet. Or just one big subnet for all applications is better?

Do service discovery internally (inside overlay network) from one service to another is easy, Docker internal DNS solves it, we just need to use `--net-alias` parameter.

But how external service discovery can be done? One from another machine/service outside the overlay network.

Can you share your experience or your thoughts about it?

Regards

Comment: Did you consider using Docker Networking to bind all Docker hosts together? Also, I'd use something like Consul for service discovery myself.

Comment: Hi, @advance512, thank you for your reply. Yes, our plan is to use Docker networking, in specific, an overlay network. It will allow us to have many hosts working as a big one. But my question is, should we create one overlay network and put all applications on it? Or should we create one overlay network per application and isolating every application from each other? We use Consul together with Docker and Swarm to do the discovery, but it only work inside docker network, not outside. I means, basic DNS, without have to code anything. How to do the discovery from a host outside Docker network?

Comment: If the applications are completely separate, I'd leave them completely separate, different networks etc. Then the service discovery, etc via Consul becomes obvious - there is one cluster per application. What else would you need from outside?